# Debugging Ruby and Rails code inside Sonar plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

What is the way to debug Rails and Ruby code (i.e. breakpoints, call stack etc...) which is running inside a separate JVM using IDE (IntelliJ Idea)?  What configuration is required for it in Sonarqube and IntelliJ?
I did not find this information on Sonarqube site or elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Extend+Web+Application.
See section Applications -> Development mode.

Regards

Comment: There is a useful information there, but it does not say anything about debugging code using IDE (i.e. stopping on breakpoints etc...)

Comment: I'm not aware of being able to set some break point in rails code.
On my side, I'm using some good old : puts "### Blabla" to understand what happen...

Comment: There is such option.  See for example https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/features/ruby_debugger.html    Using "puts" works too, but productivity will be completely different.

Comment: You can put `binding.pry` at arbitrary point in code to pause execution and drop into pry console. This will work in the context of a Rails server as well. This is not an IDE way though and will require some setup. See [Pry Runtime invocation](https://github.com/pry/pry#runtime-invocation) for more.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to go with RubyMine: https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/

It's a version of Intellij for Ruby and Rails. It's got excellent debugging tools. You can find more information about how to set breakpoints and so forth here: https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/features/ruby_debugger.html

RubyMine is gaining popularity, but most ruby developers just drop a `binding.pry` at the point in their code they want to debug. `Pry` is an extremely popular gem that offers great debugging tools. Here's more info on how to use that particular feature: https://github.com/pry/pry#runtime-invocation